# Up navigation reloads loader but back navigation doesn't

Tags: android, loader, up-button

I am using an AsyncTaskLoader to load data into an ArrayList coming from an HTTPRequest. Once loaded, data is displayed via recycler view as a list. When I click on an item of the list, an activity B gets triggered showing a detailed screen for that data. Then, I have two options to come back to the list, one is via back button (phone), and the other is via the up button **<-** on the toolbar since avtivity B it has `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`implemented.

Well, back button doesn't trigger the loader, but upbutton reloads the whole thing.  What is going on?  I want both to behave the same, that is, not reload as I specify in `onStartLoading()`.

This is my AsynTask loader which is called as usual, by implementing the `LoaderCallbacks<List<T>>` interface

```
public class FallaLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Falla>> {
private String mUrl;
private List<Falla> mFalla;

FallaLoader(Context context, String url)
{
    super(context);
    mUrl = url;
}
@Override
protected void onStartLoading()
{
    if (mFalla == null) {
        // we have no data, so kick off loading
        forceLoad();
    }
    else {
        // use cached data, fallas won't change for a year, so... just needed everytime I start
        deliverResult(mFalla);
    }
}

// This happens in the Background thread
@Override
public List<Falla> loadInBackground()
{
    if (mUrl == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
    // pass the context since it will be needed to get the preferences
    return Utils.fetchFallasData(mUrl, getContext());
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(List<Falla> data)
{
    // We’ll save the data for later retrieval
    mFalla = data;
    super.deliverResult(data);
}}
```

In `onCreate` of Activity A, I have the call to loader like this

`LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);

and then, I implement the interface:

```
    @Override
public Loader<List<Falla>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle)
{
    return new FallaLoader(this, F_URL);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Falla>> loader, List<Falla> fallas)
{
    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_fallas);

    if (fallas != null && !fallas.isEmpty())
    {
        adapter.swap(fallas);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Falla>> loader) {

}
```

`

Thanks!

Comment: Post you main activity where you are handling data and back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you come back from `activity B`, `onStartLoading` will be called again as loader is aware of the activity states.Now when you *press back button* of the **phone**, activity will be simply brought to front but if you *press back button* in **toolbar**, previous activity will be **created again**, hence your loader will be reinitialized and `if (mFalla == null)` will become true, resulting in call to `forceLoad()`.

You can handle your toolbar's back button click explicitly in `activity B` to avoid this behavior.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed(); 
        }
        return true;
    }
```